Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: "this.masterDao" is null
Я начинающий программист, делаю свой проект на javaFX и Spring, при попытке зарегистрироваться, у меня возникает ошибка с MasterDao (слоя для взаимодействия с базой данных), пишет что он пустой, хотя при авторизации все работает корректно, ниже прилагаю LoginController, RegistrationController (который работает), main и Spring конфиг а так же ссылку на свой проект в git-hub, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь)
package project.orgtech.frontController.auth;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import project.orgtech.StartApplication;
import project.orgtech.dao.MasterDao;
import project.orgtech.models.Master;

import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private MasterDao masterDao; // Injected by Spring

    @FXML
    private TextField loginText;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordText;

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private Button registrationButton;

    @FXML
    private void handleLoginButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Master master = masterDao.findMasterByLogin(loginText.getText());
        if (master != null && master.getPassword().equals(passwordText.getText())) {
            Stage currentStage = (Stage) loginButton.getScene().getWindow();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/project/orgtech/request/main-view.fxml"));
            loader.setControllerFactory(StartApplication.getContext()::getBean);
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Stage newStage = new Stage();
            newStage.setTitle("Главное окно");
            newStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            newStage.show();
            currentStage.close();
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Ошибка");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Логин или пароль неверный");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleRegistrationButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) registrationButton.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/project/orgtech/auth/registration-view.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Stage newStage = new Stage();
        newStage.setTitle("Регистрация");
        newStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        newStage.show();
        currentStage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        // Initialization logic if necessary
    }
}

package project.orgtech.frontController.auth;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import project.orgtech.dao.MasterDao;
import project.orgtech.models.Master;

import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private MasterDao masterDao; // Injected by Spring

    @FXML
    private TextField loginText;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordText;

    @FXML
    private TextField firstNameText;

    @FXML
    private TextField lastNameText;

    @FXML
    private TextField middleNameText;

    @FXML
    private Button registerButton;

    @FXML
    private Button backButton;

    @FXML
    private void handleRegisterButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String login = loginText.getText();
        String password = passwordText.getText();
        String firstName = firstNameText.getText();
        String lastName = lastNameText.getText();
        String middleName = middleNameText.getText();

        if (login.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || firstName.isEmpty() || lastName.isEmpty()) {
            showAlert("Ошибка", "Все поля должны быть заполнены");
            return;
        }

        Master newMaster = new Master();
        newMaster.setLogin(login);
        newMaster.setPassword(password);
        newMaster.setFirstName(firstName);
        newMaster.setLastName(lastName);
        newMaster.setMiddleName(middleName);

        masterDao.addMaster(newMaster);
        showAlert("Успех", "Регистрация прошла успешно");

        navigateToLogin();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBackButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        navigateToLogin();
    }

    private void navigateToLogin() throws IOException {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) backButton.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/project/orgtech/auth/login-view.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Stage newStage = new Stage();
        newStage.setTitle("Вход");
        newStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        newStage.show();
        currentStage.close();
    }

    private void showAlert(String title, String content) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(content);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        // Initialization logic if necessary
    }
}


package project.orgtech.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "project.orgtech")
public class dbConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("project.orgtech");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");

        return properties;
    }
}

package project.orgtech;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import project.orgtech.config.dbConfig;

public class StartApplication extends Application {

    @Getter
    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize Spring context
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(dbConfig.class);
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/project/orgtech/auth/login-view.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);  // Use Spring context to load controllers
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Вход");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        context.close();  // Close Spring context when application stops
    }
}

https://github.com/AleksandrSherbakov/Org-Tech/tree/main/src/main

Я нашел в чем было дело, спринг не мог создать бин так как у меня не был прописан конфиг при вызове для страницы RegistrationController, в классе Main он был
loader.setControllerFactory(StartApplication.getContext()::getBean);

добавил эту строку и все заработало :)
